# Use shopify as a prelaunchr site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

Pls let me know if I can use shopify as an prelaunchr site like harry's [prelaunchr](https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr).what will be its requirments and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes You can use your shopify store like a prelaunchr site like harry's.
In your shopify store there is one option for same, please follow below.

> Go to shopify admin > Settings > Online Store > Storefront password

in online store you will find option for Storefront password, please enable to set a password for your store and thats it.
now your store will work like a prelaunchr site for outer audience. They can share your store to social media like Fb, twitter, and G+. Every user has to fill his/her email to get notifications about your store. by this way you will be able to get number of email into your store database.